# How to model bind a tag helper in asp.net core razor

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

Is there a way for me to replace the functionality of `Html.EditorFor(m => m.ListOfItems)` in Asp.net Core Razor pages?

I was looking at tag helpers which remind me of components, however I haven't been able to get these to model bind correctly (in a loop). Am I basically forced to use editor templates for now?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-2.1#the-input-tag-helper), this is exactly the method show. This means there is no direct tag helper solution anytime soon.

However, instead of doing this with editor templates, you can always create a partial view that uses tag helpers for your `Item` class. You can then use the partial tag helper like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.ListOfItems)
{
    <partial name="MyItem" model="item" />
}
```

Comment: I think I've tried that in the past and the partial views don't model bind correctly because the name attribute in the html doesn't get set properly. I guess I'll stick to editor templates for now. Thank you

Comment: yes, the name attribute you need to use without .cshtml